# Creating a Namespace in Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I am struggling to set up a working name space in Laravel 4, I've read some guides on here and in the code bright book. But I still can't seem to figure it out. My app is set up as follows:

app/controllers/itemController
app/services/itemValidator

in my composer json file (which I dump-autoload evertime it gets changed) I have:

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        <usual data...>
        "app/repositories",
        "app/services",
    ],
    "psr-0": {
        "Services": "app/services/"
    }
```

my items controller is set up as:

```
<?php
use Services\ItemValidator;

class ItemsController extends BaseController {

public function store()
{
   $validator = new ItemValidator;
.....etc.....
```

and my ItemsValidator class is set up as:

```
 <?php namespace Services;

 class ItemValidator extends BaseValidator
 {
 ....code....
```

Which gives me the following error when it gets to the `$validator = new ItemValidator` line:

```
Class 'Services\ItemValidator' not found
```

Comment: Is your class appearing in vendor/composer/autoload_classmap.php?

Comment: no it isn't in there - I searched for 'ItemValidator'

Comment: In the vendor/composer/autoload_namespaces.php file there is the following entry though: `'Services' => array($baseDir . '/app/services'),`

Comment: Drop this "psr-0" line you added and then composer dump again, because "app/services" in classmap should be enough.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just to clarify: according to comments, what works in this case is a composer.json formatted this way:

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        <usual data...>
        "app/repositories",
        "app/services",       <---- this is the only entry needed to autoload your services
    ],
```

Then you should execute

```
composer dump-autoload
```

And check if your class appeared in the file

```
vendor/composer/autoload_namespaces.php
```

Answer (score 0):

what I believe you want to do is

```
<?php namespace Services;

 class ItemValidator extends Basevalidator
 { 
  .....
```

Then instead of using the class name in the name space, use the name space then extend the validator

```
<?php
  uses Services;

  class ItemsController extends ItemValidator
  {
```

I believe thats what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I do not want to extend the Validator class, I am just trying use an instance of ItemValidator within the controller class.

Comment: Ahh I see.  What are you trying to get the new instance inside the class for?

Answer (score 0):

app/admin/foocontroller.php

in composer.json:

```
"psr-0":{
    "App\\Controller\\Admin" : "app/controller/admin"
}
```

composer dump-autoload -o

foocontroller.php

```
<?php namespace App\Controller\Admin;
class foocontrolelr extends \BaseController
{
    public function index(){}
}
```